# search option does not appear on the page

Tags: php, sql

This is how I'm going to make the search options on the website.

when I add `WHERE name = '%$name%"` to sql, so it does not work in some manner. but if I take it away and the exclusive `SELECT name, link, img, area FROM test dyslexic` and then the content appears on the page.

t will not display the contents of the database instance if I search for "**Denmark**"

```
if($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT `navn`, `link`, `img`, `omrade` FROM `ordblindtest` WHERE `navn` = "%$navn%"'))
         {
             $stmt->bind_param('s', $navn);
             $navn = $_POST["sogord"];
```

If it is such that I have written it like this, so there are no problems on the page at all in some manner.

```
if($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT `navn`, `link`, `img`, `omrade` FROM `ordblindtest`'));
```

the problem is how in the first sql then no content appears on the page when I was searching for something in the database.

- My problem is that it does not find some content for my sql as I describe in the first piece of code.

Comment: Are you trying to use the `%` as a wildcard, or are they literally part of the name?

Comment: use the `LIKE` keyword, instead of `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the `%` as a wildcard you need to use `LIKE` rather than `=`. Also, because you're using prepared statements you should be using the `?` placeholder instead of the variables.

```
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('

  SELECT
    `navn`,
    `link`,
    `img`,
    `omrade`
  FROM
    `ordblindtest`
  WHERE
    `navn` LIKE CONCAT("%", ?, "%")
    OR
    `omrade` LIKE CONCAT("%", ?, "%")

'))
{

  $stmt->bind_param('ss', $navn, $omrade);

  // ...
```

Comment: How do I do if I need more of? Thus "omrade" and "sogord"

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409112/search-for-three-areas-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you use the statement you're using, you use it like this:

```
WHERE name LIKE %".$name."%"
```

Notice I didn't use the "=" sign. I hope this helps.

Comment: EDIT:

I think I misunderstood the question. Let me recheck my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Variables do not get parsed when you use single quotes, so your query will literally search for the string `$navn`.

```
'SELECT `navn`, `link`, `img`, `omrade` FROM `ordblindtest` WHERE `navn` = "' . $navn . '"'
```

Although you really should use a placeholder and not inject your variable directly in the query:

```
    'SELECT `navn`, `link`, `img`, `omrade` FROM `ordblindtest` WHERE `navn` = ?'
```

And the `%` is used when you use `LIKE`, not when you compare.