# search for three areas at the same time,

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

this is how I have created [search option does not appear on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407213/search-option-does-not-appear-on-the-page/21407277?noredirect=1#21407277) this thread and the fine I have to work but this is how I should look for 3 fields in the table, and it works in any way.

```
if($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT `navn`, `link`, `img`, `omrade` FROM `ordblindtest` WHERE `navn` LIKE "%" . $navn . "%" OR `omrade` LIKE "%" . $omrade . "%" OR `sogord` LIKE "%" . $sogord . "%"'))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $navn, $omrade, $sogord);
        $navn = $_POST["sogord"];
        $omrade = $_POST["sogord"];
        $sogord = $_POST["sogord"];
        ...
    }
```

Problem is that I get this error:

> Error on: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '. $navn . "%", OR `omrade` LIKE "%" . $omrade . "%", OR `sogord`
>   LIKE "%" . $sog' at line 1

I do not understand why it appears with the error. Why am I receiving the error?

Comment: You're injecting variables into your query. That's not how to use prepared statements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [search option does not appear on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407213/search-option-does-not-appear-on-the-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using prepared statements you should be using the `?` placeholder instead of the variables, and so your query should look like this:

```
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('

  SELECT
    `navn`,
    `link`,
    `img`,
    `omrade`
  FROM
    `ordblindtest`
  WHERE
    `navn` LIKE CONCAT("%", ?, "%")
    OR
    `omrade` LIKE CONCAT("%", ?, "%")
    OR
    `sogord` LIKE CONCAT("%", ?, "%")

'))
{

  $stmt->bind_param('sss', $navn, $omrade, $sogord);

  // ...
```